# tcpdf output(filename.pdf) - filename does not show russian characters

Tags: filenames, tcpdf

The problem is that when I want to set filename with russian characters and download the pdf file it does not show the filename. For example, if I set the filename "файл.pdf" and download it the downloaded filename will be "_.pdf". How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [`tcpdf::Output`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1) replace all non Latin symbols from filename by regexp (str 7538 in tcpdf.php (6.0.059 version)):

```php
$name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]/', '', $name);
```

Second - `basename()` (in switch on 7602 str). You can use `setlocale()` for correctly work of this function;

Finally: you must make your own class extends `TCPDF`, override `Output()`, change regex by something like: `[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_\.-]` and use `setlocale()` & `basename()` or your own function for currectly get filename;

```php
class MyTCPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Output($name='doc.pdf', $dest='I'){
        //copy original code and add changes;
    }
}
```

Comment: I made it and I found more better way to make circle image, you can look to my related subject for making tcpdf circle image